# How to redirect subdomain to another server subdomain?

Tags: dns, subdomain, web-hosting

I have a nice webhosting which I want to reuse multiple times for more different projects on different domains. The hosting itself has a domain, let's say **page.com**. Now I want to store project X on the subdomain - **x.page.com**, but want people to access it from the project X own domain (assuming I own **x.com**) - **project.x.com**.

Is this possible, if the subdomain itself does not have its own IP address, so I cannot simply put an A DNS record?

Just to be clear - I don't want people to know the project runs at **x.page.com**, they should access it from **project.x.com** only.

Comment: Got any news on this one?

Comment: Not yet, haven't looked into it after I asked. I need it working in about a week, so I will try to do some further research soon.